# Loop through Nested array of Object and replace empty attribute with dynamic values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a nested object like below. The content attribute in some of the objects are empty. I need to loop through all the objects ,if it has an empty **content** attribute i need to give a value like **Default value** to it.

```
var data = [{
    title: "Admin Services",
    content: "admin",
    links: [{
        title: "Report",
        content: "",
        links: [{
            title: "Notifications",
            content: "Notify",
            links: [{
                title: "Send",
                content: "",
                links: [{
                    title: "read",
                    content: "",
                    links: [],
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        title: "Script",
        content: "script",
        links: [{
            "title": "Execute",
            content: "",
            links: []
        }]
    }, {
        title: "Process",
        content: "",
        links: []
    }]
}];

function checkEmptyContent(data){
      data.forEach((item)=>{
          if(item.links.length > 0){
             checkEmptyContent(item.links)
          }
          if(item.content === ""){    
              item.content = "Default Content";
          }
      });
}

checkEmptyContent(data); 
console.log('data',data);
```

And i got the output like below

```
[
  {
    "title": "Admin Services",
    "content": "admin",
    "links": [
      {
        "title": "Report",
        "content": "Default Content",
        "links": [
          {
            "title": "Notifications",
            "content": "Notify",
            "links": [
              {
                "title": "Send",
                "content": "Default Content",
                "links": [
                  {
                    "title": "read",
                    "content": "Default Content",
                    "links": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Script",
        "content": "script",
        "links": [
          {
            "title": "Execute",
            "content": "Default Content",
            "links": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Process",
        "content": "Default Content",
        "links": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The final requirement is ,not only add the default text but also a counter which is increments like below

```
[
  {
    "title": "Admin Services",
    "content": "admin",
    "links": [
      {
        "title": "Report",
        "content": "Default Content (0)",
        "links": [
          {
            "title": "Notifications",
            "content": "Notify",
            "links": [
              {
                "title": "Send",
                "content": "Default Content (1)",
                "links": [
                  {
                    "title": "read",
                    "content": "Default Content (2)",
                    "links": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Script",
        "content": "script",
        "links": [
          {
            "title": "Execute",
            "content": "Default Content (0)",
            "links": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Process",
        "content": "Default Content (0)",
        "links": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The counter should start with 0 for each of the objects in the array

Comment: `function checkEmptyContent(data, level) { ... }`

Comment: what is the occurrence logic? parent object wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion for this, by repeating the `addDefault()` function for each nested array. By looping over each object in the array, you can check whether or not it has `content`, if it doesn't, you can add your "Default Content (0)" string to it:

```js
const data = [{title:"Admin Services",content:"admin",links:[{title:"Report",content:"",links:[{title:"Notifications",content:"Notify",links:[{title:"Send",content:"",links:[{title:"read",content:"",links:[]}]}]}]},{title:"Script",content:"script",links:[{title:"Execute",content:"",links:[]}]},{title:"Process",content:"",links:[]}]}];

const addDefault = (arr, level=0) => {
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    obj.content = obj.content || `Default Content (${level++})`;
    addDefault(obj.links, level);
    level = 0;
  });
}

addDefault(data);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: the counter has to increment

Comment: @codegeek you can pass the level through and reset it after each recurse down your array (see update)

Answer (score 0):

I have Modify your logic check it, This Will work for you

```
function checkEmptyContent(data){
    data.forEach((item)=>{
        if(!item.content.length){    
            item.content = "Default Content";
        }
        if(item.links.length > 0){
           checkEmptyContent(item.links)
        }
    });
}

checkEmptyContent(data); 
console.log('data',data);
```